# calling a html file from another html file which contains a post method

Tags: php, html

how to call a  html file 2 (which shows me a picture I need) in a html file 1 which includes two text fields and a list of which the user will fill and I will recover after the in a .php file.
My problem is when I click the display button, I find myself in the .php page thanks to method = "post" action = "transfert.php found in the html file 1
I need these values to be transferred to the .php file but I do not want to head it, for cons I want to show the image I need.
Here my html file 1 :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<title>Interface</title>
</head>
<body>

<form name="form1" method="post" action="transfert.php">
<p>Date de Debut : 
<input type="text" name="date1" id="champ_date1" size="12" maxlength="20" /></p>

<p>Date de Fin : 
<input type="text" name="date2" id="champ_date1" size="12" maxlength="20" /> </p>

<p> choisir KPI  
<select name="list" size="1" id="0">
<option value="TotalVoiceTrafficBH1" id="1">TotalVoiceTrafficBH1</option>
<option value="TotalVoiceTrafficBH2" id="2">TotalVoiceTrafficBH2</option>
<option value="CSSRBH1" id="3">CSSRBH1</option>
<option value="CSSRBH2" id="4">CSSRBH2</option>
<option value="TCHBlockingBH1" id="5">TCHBlockingBH1</option>
<option value="TCHBlockingBH2" id="6">TCHBlockingBH2</option>
<option value="SDCHHBlockingBH1" id="7">SDCHHBlockingBH1</option>
<option value="SDCCHBlockingBH2" id="8">SDCCHBlockingBH2</option>
<option value="SDCCHDropBH1" id="9">SDCCHDropBH1</option>
<option value="SDCCHDropBH2" id="10">SDCCHDropBH2</option>
<option value="TCHDropBH1" id="11">TCHDropBH1</option>
<option value="TCHDropBH2" id="12">TCHDropBH2</option>
<option value="HOSRBH1" id="13">HOSRBH1</option>
<option value="HOSRBH2" id="14">HOSRBH2</option>
</select>  
</p>
<p><input type="submit" value="Afficher" size="15"/>
</p>
</form>
// here i wanna to insert my html file 2 so i can get my picture
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems as though English is not your primary language so your question is not that clear.
I can't get what your problem is and what you intend to achieve, however two observations.

1. Why not post html2 file and transfert.php. it might give us clues on why you are having problems
2. Why are you mixing php and html file types in one application ? since your site is not going to be static, I suggest you stick with using php all through

Answer (score 0):

so here is my php file and my html2 file, i need to get the chart generated by my html2 file from my html1 file. The problem is that i am automatically redirected to my transfert.php page whilst clicking on the display button, but i want to send my variables to transfert.php and get my chart from my html2 file.

```html
//transfert.php
<?php
$var1=$_POST['date1'];
$var2=$_POST['date2'];
$var3=$_POST['list'];

    if($var1 != NULL AND $var2 != NULL AND $var3 != NULL)
   {
//address of the server where db is installed
$servername = "localhost";

//username to connect to the db
//the default value is root
$username = "root";

//password to connect to the db
//this is the value you would have specified during installation of WAMP stack
$password = "";

//name of the db under which the table is created
$dbName = "test";

//establishing the connection to the db.
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbName);

//checking if there were any error during the last connection attempt
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
                           }

//the SQL query to be executed
$query = "SELECT A,$var3 FROM `feuil1` WHERE A >= '$var1' AND A<= '$var2'";

//storing the result of the executed query
$result = $conn->query($query);
 //initialize the array to store the processed data
//initialize the array to store the processed data
$jsonArray = array();
//check if there is any data returned by the SQL Query
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

  //Converting the results into an associative array
 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
  {
    $jsonArrayItem = array();
    $jsonArrayItem['label'] = $row['A'];
    $jsonArrayItem['value'] = $row[$var3];
 
    //append the above created object into the main array.
    array_push($jsonArray, $jsonArrayItem);
  }             


//Closing the connection to DB
//$conn->close();
$con = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbName);
     if ($con->connect_error) 
     {
                      die("Connection failed: " . $con->connect_error);
                    }
     
     

          if (is_array($jsonArray)) {
    
    $sql = "TRUNCATE TABLE `table_temporaire`";
    $res = $con->query($sql);

         foreach ($jsonArray as $row) { 

                    $id = $row['label'];
                    $na = $row['value']; 
 $st = $con-> prepare("INSERT INTO `table_temporaire`(A, $var3) VALUES (?, ?)");
    $st->bind_param('ss', $id, $na);
     
             $st->execute();
 
                                     
           }
                                   }
           
        }
     $con->close();
    }
  if($var1 == NULL)
    {
        echo 'Vous devez entrer date de Debut';
    }
    if($var2 == NULL)
    {
        echo 'Vous devez entrer date de Fin';
    }
 
       
  ?>
```

```html
   // file2.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Fusion Charts Column 2D Sample</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="chart-container">FusionCharts will render here</div>
  <script src="js/jquery-2.1.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="js/fusioncharts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="js/fusioncharts.charts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="js/themes/fusioncharts.theme.zune.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="js/atr1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Aha! I see!
I think it will make your life easier if you use the fusionchart.php wrapper.

This allows you to load your data from the database,
Encode in a jsonarray and then call it like below

```
$columnChart = new FusionCharts("column2D", "myFirstChart" , 600, 300, "chart-1", "json", $jsonEncodedData);
// Render the chart
$columnChart->render();
```

Comment: you see that div into html2 file ?

Comment: I created a javascript file which render my chart into that id, all is good with that fusion chart. Besides when i run my file2.html i get the chart i need, my problem is to get this chart into the same page html1 file where the user introduce his variables. I want to create a button or smthg which allow me to have the chart in the same page !

Comment: If you want to process POST data, you need a server side language e.g. PHP. As I advised, if you use fusionchart.php, you will only need one php file to implement what you want.